# Duplicated code First MVC many to many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, many-to-many, code-first

My models :

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int IdPerson { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int IdProject {get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }
}
```

My context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Members)
        .WithMany(e => e.Projects)
        .Map(pe =>
        {
            pe.ToTable("ProjectPersonTable");
            pe.MapLeftKey("IdPerson");
            pe.MapRightKey("IdProject");
        });
}
```

Now when I do this:

```
 Person person = personRepository.GetSingle(Idperson);
 project.Members.Add(person);
```

Doubles the person, I do not want duplicates or to insert a new person when I do this.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

What context is your `project` attached to?  It's probably doubling up, because the `person` `entity` you're getting from your repository isn't in the context that your `project` object is a part of.  So when the context tries to create/update your `project` entity, it doubles it up.

Try attaching the `person` to the same context, or be sure that you have a single context across both repositories.